# How to lookup value in another table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataset, lookup-tables

I have two (actually many, but stick with two) datasets and I need to merge them together. However, they are not same range and they have different reference values. Lets consider

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
e 4
```

and

```
a 2
b 3
d 7
e 2
```

I tried to simulate Excel index and match function, but I am not able to get the right result

> ```
> b = []
> f = []
>
> for i in data1["c1"]:
>     if i in data2["c1"]:
>         a = d3[data2["c4"].index[i]]
>         f = b.append(a)
>     else:
>         continue
>
> print(f)
> ```

Can you please help me how this works? I would also welcome some link with further information about this topic. Thank you

Comment: Can you post current and wanted output?

Comment: Are you using pandas dataframes? Or another "table"? Please create sample input and output and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Current output is an empty list, such as f is defined. My desired output is a list of values from second table such that it corresponds to the first collumn of the first table, in my example with two tables i would love have f = [2,3,NA,2]

Comment: I load 2 different csv files with pandas read_csv function, then I take desired columns as pandas series.

Comment: first of all, the `else: continue` is unnecessary. The loop will continue anyways. Then You are working with data1 and data2, that is understandable as the two data tables. but what is d3, and your keys "c1" or "c4"? More clarification of your code would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a consolidated file from the two above like:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3
  a     1    2
  b     2    3
  c     3    7
  d     4    2
```

You can simply use dictionaries, with `keys` as your column 1 values: `a, b, c, d` and values as `list` of the 2nd column values from your two DataFrames respectively like:

```
your_dict = {a:[1,2], b:[2,3], c:[3,7], d:[4,2]}
```

Then to output that into one DataFrame such as the one above, just use the `.from_dict()` method in pandas with the `orient` parameter equal to `'index'` see documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).